# Why i need a wp loop in single.php

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

In WordPress theme development we can use `single.php` to show the specific single post.

For this purpose the common practice is:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <?php the_content();?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Why do I need looping to show a single post? Can any one give some valid reason?

Comment: See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/198704/should-i-use-loop-in-the-single-php-file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [WordPress Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) instantiates some functions like [`the_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_title), [`the_content()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_content) and [others](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/).

In other words, your post is *loaded* in that loop, and the loop is gone through once if you are on a single post. Although it might be strange to have a loop, it is actually quite useful.

WordPress uses a [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy), which is a way of choosing which template to load for a given post/page. In your `single.php`, the loop will run once. But if you do not have a `single.php` file, WordPress will use `index.php` instead for that same post.

For the sake of consistency, having a loop which works for any number of posts is helpful. Else, in you `index.php`, you would have needed a case for one post and another case for multiple posts and keeping a consistent templating method would be difficult.

Comment: You are wrong here. The `the_post()` call does what you said. Not the entire loop.
Also, since there exists a `single.php` we aren't in `index.php` thus we don't really need that loop. Only a call to `the_post()`

Comment: The comment about the "loop_end" trigger not firing which can impact how some plugins work as noted by @paulgagu below is a great point about why you might want to keep The Loop in single.php.

Answer (score 21):

this was something that killed me for years and I found the answer:
No, you don't need to use the LOOP in single pages, you just call the_post() and you have all data needed

```
.... BUT ....
```

If you don't use the loop (while(have_posts())....) a hook "loop_end" is not called and if a plugin/process has any action on this hook, it won't work. So for safety reasons you should use the loop.

Also, people ask do I need to check for existence before the loop: if(have_posts())?

```
<?
if( have_posts() ):
    while( have_posts() ):
        the_post();
        .....
    endwhile;
endif
?>
```

No, you don't need to check

```
.... BUT ....
```

Checking allows you to include headers/titles before the loop and not having them if the loop is empty.

Comment: Finally a useful answer, yup plugins thats why

Comment: Sooo... Those pesky plugins will go wrong (from having no "loop-end") if there's no posts, the "if" will not change that? OK. Then I'll only have the IF (and probably an ELSE!) should I want separate layout/content for no-posts.

Comment: [Can't edit so second comment, sorry:] To clarify, While( have_posts() ) if there's no posts won't run --- so there's no loop_end firing? Or does it still fire? That would make a difference between using the IF or not.

Comment: `loop_end` fires even when the body of the `while( have_posts() )` loop does not run, because the condition `have_posts()` is evaluated anyway. However if the whole thing is wrapped in `if( have_posts() )` and there are no posts, the `have_posts()` will not be evaluated and `loop_end` will not fire. You can as a workaround call `have_posts()` in an `else` branch as well, but without a `while` loop.

Comment: @sbnc.eu I thought the same, that wrapping The Loop in a conditions might lead to skipping the `loop_end`. But since the condition in `if ( have_posts() )` is calling the very same function as in `while ( have_posts() )`, calling it a second time in an else branch won't change anything.

Comment: Adding to this, from the code in https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/have_posts/ it appears that the `loop_end` action will __not__ be fired for empty loops either way. Instead, there is a separate `loop_no_results` action.

Comment: I don't really know hat I wanted to say. It is really confusing. The part is right about there is no need to warp the `while( have_posts() )` in `if( have_posts() )`, because `have_posts()` is executed anyway, but the rest is a mess. Sorry.