# Wordpress - get_the_author_meta() not working when id field is not specified

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to simply display the name and description of the post author on my single.php page through the get_the_author_meta() function but I can only get it to return a value when I fill the id field with a number what is not ideal as the author changes depending on the post. I really don't understand why wordpress isn't getting the current post author's id by default. Can someone help me?

Here's the code I'm using

```
<div class="col-8 col-md-10">
        <?php $id=get_the_author_meta('ID'); echo $id ?>//getting the author's id this way doesn't work
        <h2><?php echo get_the_author_meta('nickname',1);?></h2>//this works but only because I filled the id field with a valid number
        <p><?php echo get_the_author_meta('user_description') ?></p>//this doesn't workalso
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Managed to solve it using get_post_field( 'post_author' ). I'm not in the Loop but in a regular post so I needed to use this function to get the author's id and from that I managed to get the the rest working

Here's the code

```
<div class="col-8 col-md-10">
        <?php $id=get_post_field( 'post_author' )?>
        <h2><?php echo get_the_author_meta('first_name',$id).' '.get_the_author_meta('last_name',$id);?></h2>
        <p><?php echo get_the_author_meta('user_description',$id) ?></p>
    </div>
```

Comment: you may wish to refactor things such that this is inside The Loop, if it’s meant to be metadata for the Post you’re looking at, but if this works, great!

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs on `get_the_author_meta()`](http://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_meta/):

> If used within [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), the user ID need not be specified, it defaults to current post author. A user ID must be specified if used outside [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop).

Based on your sharing that it won’t work without the user ID, I suspect you are not inside The Loop. Without seeing more of your `single.php` template, it’s hard to say, so if you can share more, that would help.

Comment: `single.php` is in the loop by default.

Comment: @disinfor that’s not necessarily true; WordPress will use `single.php` when you visit a single Post, following the [Template Hierarchy for a single Post](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-post).

Comment: As OP mentions in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67795963/133479), they’re not in The Loop.

Comment: I think we're arguing semantics, since the template hierarchy will call `single.php` you don't need the loop, since WP is already calling it in the hierarchy. Check out the first comment on the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21249888/why-i-need-a-wp-loop-in-single-php

Comment: As the answer you link to points out, you still need to be in The Loop. I.e., your `single.php` needs to include the `while` loop. The Template Hierarchy only dictates which PHP file WordPress loads; if what’s loaded does not have The Loop defined, then you’ve no Loop!

Comment: The loop is unnecessary. You can test this. Make a single.php and simply put `the_content()` (with get_header and get_footer) and it will output the content.

Comment: Per [the docs on `the_content()`](http://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/), it doesn’t specify that it needs to be inside The Loop, whereas `get_the_author_meta()` _does_ specify that, so while what you say is true, it may be there’s something else that means `the_content()` works without The Loop in `single.php`, while `get_the_author_meta()` does not. ‍♂️